# D3 v4: Reset zoom state

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming

I have a SVG which can be zoomed and also a "reset" button. I'm resetting the zoom with

```
zoom.transform(selection, d3.zoomIdentity)
```

This works as expected and resets the zoom on the SVG. But if I zoom again, it zooms back to the last state. E.g. I scroll in, press "reset" button and then zoom out -> SVG is zoomed in. How can I reset the internal zoom state of the `zoom` object? Tried out different solutions and none of them works.

Here the full zoom code

```
//zoom cannot be done on the <svg> directly
var container = d3.select("#g5063")

var zoom = d3.zoom().
    scaleExtent([0.7, 8]).
    on("zoom", () => {       
        container.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)                
    })

$("#reset-zoom-button").click(() => {
    zoom.transform(container, d3.zoomIdentity);
})

var svg = d3.select("#svg").call(zoom)
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48790190/2506522, however that is newwer, but with a solution

Comment: the solution below works for me while the solution of the above link doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same problem using

```
this.svg.selectAll('g').call(this.zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1));
```

and I change to

```
this.svg.call(this.zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1));
```

soloved the problem.

I think the `_zoom` will be stored in the `svg` level also.

Answer (score 2):

This [gist](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/44), which points to [this working sample](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/hjiMeumJzL10TmWKkijV/), ended up pointing me to the solution at least for my situation. As far as I can tell, it should fix your issue too.

What you're missing is that you need to tell `zoomIdentity` what the initial `x`, `y`, and `k` states should be. The `x` and `y` state is set using `.translate(x,y)` and the scale is set using `.scale(k)`. The code below should work.

```
$("#reset-zoom-button").click(() => {
  zoom.transform(container, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(0,0).scale(0.7));
})
```

From what I can tell, translating the `zoomIdentity` to 0,0 should always reset the svg to the initial settings position settings, but it's possible you'll have to play around with this.

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with the same issue and solved it by changing to the following line.

```
svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1));
```

Here is the complete code.

```
//zoom cannot be done on the <svg> directly
var container = d3.select("#g5063")

var zoom = d3.zoom().
    scaleExtent([0.7, 8]).
    on("zoom", () => {       
        container.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)                
    })

$("#reset-zoom-button").click(() => {
    svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1));
})

var svg = d3.select("#svg").call(zoom)
```

Here is testable script.

```js
//zoom cannot be done on the <svg> directly
var container = d3.select("#g5063")

var zoom = d3.zoom().
    scaleExtent([0.7, 8]).
    on("zoom", () => {       
        container.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)                
    })

$("#reset-zoom-button").click(() => {
    svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(250, 100).scale(1))
})

var svg = d3.select("#svg").call(zoom)
svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(250, 100).scale(1))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" width="500" height="200">
  <g id="g5063">
    <polyline
       fill="none"
       stroke="#0074d9"
       stroke-width="3"
       points="
         0,120
         20,60
         40,80
         60,20"/>
  </g>
</svg>
<button id="reset-zoom-button">Reset</button>
```

Comment: I did this, but when I zoom again, it jumps back to the opld state.

Answer (score 1):

> This works as expected and resets the zoom on the SVG. But if I zoom again, it zooms back to the last state.

I have the same problem, after a quick research I discovered. You cant apply zoom and reset zoom to `<svg>`, you need to append `<g>` and apply zoom there.

```
svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1));
```

Changed to
`zoom.transform(d3.select(chartContainer).select('svg.view'), d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1));`  it works for me.

Comment: I think it would be easier to read if you put your comment into your answer

Answer (score 0):

Also set scale in the reset

```
$("#reset-zoom-button").click(() => {
    zoom.transform(container, d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1) );

})
```

Comment: are you using v4 ?

Comment: 4.10.0 to be exact. Edit: I dont get an error with your updated answer, but the problem is still here

Comment: @ierqjirj13r109r1 finally do you resolve this problem? I have the same problem