# How to reset Zoom in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a simple svg rectangle and I have added zooming and panning on it using d3.js. I have also added a button in order to try and reset the zoom once the button is clicked. Here is the code:

```
<button>Reset</button>
<body>
  <script>

      function zoomed() {
              svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
      }

    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed))
      .append("g")

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 450)
        .attr("y", 200)
        .attr("width", 300)
        .attr("height", 200)
        .style("fill", "#B8DEE6")

    $("#Reset").click(() => {
    zoom.transform(container, d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1));
})

  </script>
</body>
```

I have tried zoom.transform(container, d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1)) but it does not seem to work. Can anybody please tell what is the problem with the resetting function?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45570145/2506522, which has no accepted answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to rewrite your code this way:

```
function zoomed() {
  gElem.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}

var zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "600")
  .attr("height", "600")


var gElem = svg.append("g").call(zoom);

gElem.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 200)
  .style("fill", "#B8DEE6")

$("#Reset").click(() => {
  gElem.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
});
```

Check demo:

```js
function zoomed() {
  gElem.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}

var zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "400")
  .attr("height", "200")
  

var gElem = svg.append("g").call(zoom);

gElem.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 200)
  .style("fill", "#B8DEE6")

$("#Reset").click(() => {
  gElem.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Reset">RESET</button>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help

Comment: I'm glad to help. It is strange to downvote when questioner accepted the answer.