# How to stop reset zoom and pan on d3 graph from shifting on first click?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have implemented a d3 tree graph, with a d3 zoom element. Currently, I have been trying to implement a reset on the zoom and pan. Unfortunately, when I try to implement a reset it does reset the zoom and pan until I click on the graph. At that point, it goes back to where I was zoomed and panned before.

I tried implementing what was answered in this Stack Overflow question: [How to reset Zoom in d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790190/how-to-reset-zoom-in-d3-js), but the OP of that post wasn't using a child group to change the transform. I would like a way to have a permanent reset of zoom and pan for my d3 graph, but I haven't found any resources for my scenario.

```
  //Zoom function so I can reset it later
  let zoom = d3.zoom().on(`zoom`, function() {
    //This was to part of the solution to stop it from shifting on first 
    //click after initial graph creation
    svgZoom.attr(`transform`, d3.event.transform)
  })

  //The main zoom element, which calls the zoom function
  let svgZoom = d3
    .select(cfg.el)
    .append(`svg`)
    .attr(`viewBox`, `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
    .attr(`width`, `75%`)
    .style(`max-height`, `${height}px`)
    .style(`margin-left`, `12.5%`)
    .style(`margin-top`, `${margin.top}`)
    .on(`contextmenu`, () => d3.event.preventDefault())
    .call(zoom)
    .on(`dblclick.zoom`, null)
    .append(`g`)

  //This piece of code translates the graph
  svg = svgZoom
    .append(`g`)
    .attr(`id`, `graph`)
    .attr(`transform`, `translate(` + width / 4 + `,0)`)

  //This I found this functionality on another Stack Overflow question, 
  //but it is not resetting to my base transition, and the reset only 
  //works until I click, then it goes back to where it was before.
  let resetZoomPan = () => {
    svgZoom.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity)
  }
```

TLDR: I would like to reset my zoom and pan of my graph when I call a function, but currently it reverts after the first click.

Comment: I don't have time to build an answer - but I would say that the issue may have something to do with calling zoom and zoom.transform on different selections - you call the zoom on the `svg`, then apply a zoom transform on the child `g` - not updating the zoom transform on the `svg`. Try calling zoom on the `g` originally: it just means you use .call(zoom) after  you append the `g` in your method chain.

Comment: @AndrewReid Unfortunately, if I chain the zoom after the `g` then the zoom doesn't happen at all, and if I remove the appended `g` then the SVG itself will try to pan and zoom around my screen.