# DataMap/D3 - how to reset zoom?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datamaps

I have a [DataMaps](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps) map, which is based on D3.js (version 3), and I've added a zoom on scroll to it. The only problem is that I haven't found a way how to reset it.

```
var reset = document.getElementById('reset-map');
var map = new Datamap({
     element: document.getElementById('world-map'),
     responsive: true,       
});
map.svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', function () {
     reset.style.display = 'block';
     map.svg.selectAll('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate + ')' + ' scale(' + d3.event.scale + ')')
}));
reset.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // TODO remove zoom
     reset.style.display = 'none';
} );
```

Found these two, but I have no idea how to apply it in my case, could you help, please?

- https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/107
- [How to reset Zoom in d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790190/how-to-reset-zoom-in-d3-js)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', function () {...});
map.svg.call(zoom);
```

On reset (it's a V4 code, not sure it works with V3):

```
var transform = d3.zoomIdentity.translate(0, 0).scale(1);
map.svg.call(zoom.transform, transform);
```

Let us know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks, ut doesn't work because of `d3.zoomIdentity` is undefined in v3, however, you pointed me the right direction. Not probably the best solution, but working: `map.svg.selectAll('g').attr('transform', 'translate(0,0) scale(1)');`. :)

Comment: I wasn't the one downvoting, however, it's not an answer to my question (so anybody else who will step by could use it as solution), I've found a way how to hack it around, you could use it in your answer, however, I'm pretty sure that there has to be a proper way to do it which I would love to know.