# D3 chart zoom and reset functionality in Angular

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am using D3 chart to display data in my angular project.

I have a function called drawChart() which displays the chart perfectly.
within this function I am using like so.

```
  svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
      }))
```

for the zoom in/out and pan functionality its working fine.

I am also trying to implement the zoom reset function like so.

```
  reset(){
    let d3: any = D3;
    let svg = d3.select('#line-chart');
    let zoom = d3.zoom();
    svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(0, 0).scale(1));
  }
```

and trying to call it in my HTML via button click event, but it is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please try this: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790190/how-to-reset-zoom-in-d3-js)

Comment: tried implementing this.. 
  reset() {
    let d3: any = D3;
    let svg = d3.select("#chart");

    let zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
      svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
    });
    svg.transition().duration(750).call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity)
  }                                                                                                                                  
   the reset function does not work for me. Its not resetting the chart

Comment: The doc says like `selection.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);`, nothing else. Tried ? Also could you please make a shareable link for the project

Comment: reset(){
    let d3: any = D3;
    let container = d3.select("g");
    
    let zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", () => {       
        container.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)                
    })

    container.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(40, 40).scale(1))

  }                                                                                                                                                 I have implemented the reset function as shown above, but only works when I do d3.select("g"). It does not work If a try to select element by Id.

Comment: I mean did you try using just the transform and zoomIdentity only, without translate and scale.

Comment: Yea I tried it first like you mentioned it did not work.